# How to know if point is on the right side or on the left side of line

Tags: java, algorithm, math, vector

I talking about 3D
I have 2 points on a plane(A and B) and I made a Vector AB (B-A) from them. I have made a line with point A and Vector AB. On the same plane I have another point. I want to know if the point is on the right side or on the left side of the line I have made.
Thanks for help..

Comment: Important note: the right and left of a vector have a precise meaning; the right and left of a line is ambiguous. Consider for instance A = (0, 0) and B = (0, -1): the left half-plane is on the right of vector AB and the right half-plane is on the left of vector AB.

Answer (score 1):

You have got your two points A, B, and a third point C.

You may already know that you can find the cosinus of an angle, using the dot product:

```
cos(AB, AC) = AB . AC / (||AB|| ||AC||)
```

Where `.` denotes the dot product and `|| ||` the Euclidean norm.

However, what you want is not the cosinus of the angle, but the sinus of the angle. The sinus `sin(AB, AC)` will be positive if `C` is on the left of `AB`, and negative if `C` is on the right of `AB`.

Let's call `D` the point obtained by taking the image of `B` by the rotation of centre `A` and angle `+Pi/2` (rotation by a quarter-turn counterclockwise).

Then it turns out that:

```
sin(AB, AC) = cos(AD, AC)
```

Furthermore, the coordinates of vector `AD` are easy to compute: if vector `AB` has coordinates `(x,y)`, then vector `AD` has coordinates `(-y, x)`.

Putting all this together, we get the following formula:

```
sin(AB,AC) = ((yA - yB)*(xC-xA) + (xB-xA)*(yC-yA)) / sqrt(((xB-xA)**2+(yB-yA)**2)*((xC-xA)**2 + (yC-yA)**2))
```

This is a number between -1 and +1. If all you care about is a "left" or "right" answer, then you only want the sign of `sin(AB,AC)`; and the denominator of this expression is always positive. Hence you only need to compute the numerator:

```
n = ((yA - yB)*(xC-xA) + (xB-xA)*(yC-yA))
if n > 0:
  print("C is on the LEFT of AB")
else if n < 0:
  print("C is on the RIGHT of AB")
else if n == 0:
  print("C is on AB")
```