# Check if the point is inside of half-plane and cut the segment

Tags: math, vector, lua

I have 4 half-planes, that are defined as base point and normalized tangent:

```
local frameX, frameY, frameW, frameH = 25, 25, 750, 550
local halfPlanes = {
--       halfplane as starting point and tangent
        {frameX, frameY, -1, 0}, -- y < frameY
        {frameX + frameW, frameY, 0, 1},  -- x > frameX + frameW
        {frameX + frameW, frameY+frameH, 1, 0}, -- y > frameY + frameH
        {frameX, frameY+frameH, 0, -1}, -- x < frameX
    }
```

I want to check if the point is in one of them / not in any of them as

```
local bx, by, tx, ty = halfPlane[1], halfPlane[2], halfPlane[3], halfPlane[4]
local d1 = dotProductLineTangentPoint (bx, by, tx, ty, px1, py1)
local d2 = dotProductLineTangentPoint (bx, by, tx, ty, px2, py2)
```

where dotProductLineTangentPoint is

```
local function dotProductLineTangentPoint (x, y, tx, ty, px, py)
-- x,y - starting point of line
-- tx, ty - normalized tangent vector of line
-- px, py - point to check
--  return tx * (px - x) + ty * (py - y)
    return ty * (px - x) + tx * (py - y)
end
```

And than if one side is positive and the other is negative, then

```
if (d1 > 0 and d2 < 0) or (d1 < 0 and d2 > 0) then
    local cx, cy = findCrossingLineTangentSegment (bx, by, tx, ty, p1, p2)
    return {cx, cy, px2, py2}
end
```

The result function crops the given segment with given boundary.

Question:
How to make the findCrossingLineTangentSegment correctly? Now I have placeholder with two exceptions for horizontal and vertical lines and not working vector solution:

```
local function findCrossingLineTangentSegment(bx, by, tx, ty, p1, p2)
    if tx == 0 then
        local x, y = findIntersectionWithVerticalLine(p1.x, p1.y, p2.x, p2.y, bx)
--      print ('cross with vertical')
        return x, y
    elseif ty == 0 then
        local x, y = findIntersectionWithHorizontalLine(p1.x, p1.y, p2.x, p2.y, by)
--      print ('cross with horizontal')
        return x, y
    else
--      local u = ((p2.x - p1.x) * ty + (p1.y - by) * tx) / (tx * (p1.y - p2.y) + ty * (p2.x - p1.x))
        local u = dotProductLineTangentPoint(bx, by, tx, ty, p1) / dotProductLineTangentPoint(bx, by, tx, ty, p1, p2)
        local cx = p1.x + u * (p2.x - p1.x)
        local cy = p1.y + u * (p2.y - p1.y)
        return cx, cy
    end
end
```

Comment: Hi. Could you please explain which variable names correspond to which mathematical object? For instance, in `findCrossingLineTangentSegment(bx, by, tx, ty, p1, p2)`, what is (bx, by)? What is (tx, ty)? What is p1? What is p2? I understand that one of those is the tangent to the half-plane, one of them is a base point of the half-plane, but which is which? And what are the others? Which one is the segment which you want to cut?

Comment: Also it's not clear to me whether the segment which you want to cut is a segment in the plane, which you want to cut if it crosses the line that delimits the half-plane, or whether it is a line outside the plane, which you want to cut if it crosses the plane.

Comment: (bx, by) is a position of base point for given half plane, the (tx, ty) is tangent of it. For example, half plane bx=0, by=0, tx=1, ty=0 is a half plane with horizontal cutting of unlimited 2D field. It contains all points that is more than by=0.
The same way I can check and cut any half plane from given infinite plane. In the example higher, it cuts all area from plane with 4 half-planes and we get just points inside/outside of rectangle (frameX, frameY, frameW, frameH). https://www.ck12.org/book/ck-12-algebra-basic/section/6.7/

Comment: Okay!!!! So to determine whether a point p is in the half-plane (base point b, tangent vector t), you need to know whether vector bp is [on the left or on the right](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68592435/how-to-know-if-point-is-on-the-right-side-or-on-the-left-side-of-line/68592731#68592731) of vector t.